# tar: p: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: tar

I am in the directory where the file.tar.gz file is located. I want to ignore `umask` by using the `-p (--preserve)` option. But I am unable to untar it with `-p` flag. What may be the reason for it?

- `tar -xvfp file.tar.gz` # does not work
- `tar -xvf file.tar.gz`  # when I remove `p` it works

```
$ ls *file.tar.gz
file.tar.gz

$ tar -xvfp file.tar.gz
tar: p: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

$ tar -xvf file.tar.gz
file.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tar` interprets the next argument after `-f` as the file name of the tar file.

Put the `p` before the `f`:

```
tar -xvpf file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Try separating `-p` from the `-f` command, as

```
tar -p -xvf file.tar.gz
```